Setting up a netdrive to use for steam library storage
I am trying to set up a netdrive on my local machine that is running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I am using Pop OS on my personal machine. I am attempting to store steam games on the drive and have not been successful. I have followed instruction for samba sharings and fstab editing for the samba share. I can see the directory in nautilus but steam does not accept the directory as an indepedent drive even when mounting it. I try finding guides online but its only for samba sharing with windows. I did find one guide that used a NAS but I don't have a NAS setup yet. Any help would be appreciated and thanks!

Were the Steam system running Ubuntu, the answer would be clear -- it's a security feature of the Steam snap. We could also tell you how to safely mount the network drive so Steam could see it. But since it's not running Ubuntu, we will refer you to Pop!OS support to help you diagnose and resolve.
